# Replace a character with control character Field Seperator(\034) in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, control-characters

```
(Get-Content C:\Users\georgeji\Desktop\KAI\KAI_Block_2\Temp\KAI_ORDER_DATARECON3.NONPUBLISH) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "~", "\034"} | Set-Content C:\Users\georgeji\Desktop\KAI\KAI_Block_2\Temp\KAI_ORDER_DATARECON4.NONPUBLISH
```

I am using the following command to replace ~ in text file with Field Seperator.
This command run sucessfully but when i open the output file in notepadd ++. I am just seeing the plain \034.

Ex:

Company_Identifier\034Primary_Transaction_ID

But the output should be like below

[image]

Please Help

Comment: Try `-replace "~", [char]0x1C`

Comment: Fantastic ...it worked..

Comment: I am new to powershell..Can you Please provide some links where i can have better idea about control characters in powershell. in unix we use \034 but it will not work in powershell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
-replace "~", [char]0x1C
```

If you want to use it inside a longer string, you may use

```
-replace "~", "more $([char]0x1C) text"
```

The point here is that, in Powershell, you cannot use an octal char representation (nor `\xYY` or `\uXXXX`) since the escape sequences that it supports is limited to (see [source](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html))

> ```
>    `0  Null
>    `a  Alert bell/beep
>    `b  Backspace
>    `f  Form feed (use with printer output)
>    `n  New line
>    `r  Carriage return
>  `r`n  Carriage return + New line
>    `t  Horizontal tab
>    `v  Vertical tab (use with printer output)
> ```
>
> The `` `r `` (carriage return) is ignored in PowerShell (ISE) Integrated Scripting Environment host application console, it does work in a PowerShell console session.
>
> Using the Escape character to avoid special meaning.
>
> ```
>    ``  To avoid using a Grave-accent as the escape character
>    `#  To avoid using # to create a comment
>    `'  To avoid using ' to delimit a string
>    `"  To avoid using " to delimit a string
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Windows PowerShell does not have currently (see below) have escape sequences for character literals like `\034`.

Instead, what you can do is cast the numerical ascii or unicode value to `[char]` in a subexpression:

```
"Company_Identifier$([char]0x1C)Primary_Transaction_ID"
```

Similarly, you can provide the same cast expression as the right-most operand to `-replace`, it'll be converted to a single-character string:

```
... |Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "~", [char]0x1C} |...
```

---

PowerShell 6.0 (currently in beta) introduces the `` `u{} `` escape sequence for unicode codepoint literals:

```
... |Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "~", "`u{1C}"} |...
```

[image: unicode literals in PowerShell 6.0.0-beta.7]